# Get argument type in PHP GraphQL

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, graphql-php

Is there a way to get the Input Type of an argument in [nuwave/lighthouse](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse) or [rebing/graphql-laravel](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel) (both use [webonyx/graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php) behind the scenes)?

Given a schema like this (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
type Query {
    users(filters: [FilterUser!]): [User!]!
}

type User {
    id: Int!
    email: String!
}

input FilterUser {
    and: [FilterUser!]
    or: [FilterUser!]
    id: FilterInt
    email: FilterString
}

input FilterInt {
    eq: Int
}

input FilterString {
    eq: String
}
```

This allows expression of queries like "email=x@y.com AND (id=1 OR id=2)", but the arguments are passed like this:

```
[
    'filters' => [
        'and' => [
            [
                'email' => [
                   [
                       'eq' => 'x@y.com',
                   ]
             ]
             ... snip OR section ...
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is there a simple way to get that, for example, `email` is of type `FilterString`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but tries to solve it in a different way. You can use the `whereConstraints` directive, which gives you a filler possibility with `and` and `or` statements.

Comment: My solution is for Lighthouse btw.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that